# Is there any way to convert a vector to euler angle?

Tags: python, vector, 3d, euler-angles

I have 2 vectors in 3D space, for example:

[image]

If I know these 4 points, is there any method to find out the euler angles of them? 
I am trying to move these two vectors to the origin, then assuming these two vectors are rotated from two reference vector, which have the same length of these two, for example (0,0,z1),(0,0,z2). But I do not know what to do next. Am I in the right way, or is there any other method to find out the euler angles?

BTW: I have got some ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613741/convert-2-3d-points-to-directional-vectors-to-euler-angles/35675525#35675525)  but I do not know the meaning of the final matrix :(

Comment: yes convert the vector you want to transform to euler angles into 3 perpendicular unit basis vectors (using cross product) and then just use this: [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950130/2521214) note that single vector have infinite euler angle configurations leading to the same direction for single axis.... if you got 2 or 3 perpendicular vectors then there is single solution for vector and plane 2 solutions...

Comment: Thank you Spektre, I will need some time to think about this.